# Execution time, high- vs. low-level programming language

Tags: performance, programming-languages, theory, low-level, high-level

When talking about execution time between high- and low-level programming languages I often hear that low-level languages performs a bit better than high-level.

Of course a low level can perform worse than a high-level depending on the programmer and algorithms. But if we use the very minimal code needed to do different tasks. Will there most often be differences in execution time due to the abstraction level of different languages?

And also, does anyone know any good books about these kind of topic?

Comment: That depends on the language, code and ability of the compiler. There's no general rule. *At best* the compiled high level code is *as fast* as the optimal implementation in low level code. How often this is the case widely varies.

Comment: @deceze: That is true only when the coder of the low-level implementation is both sufficiently competent to reproduce the quality produced by a modern compiler, and has the time to do so. Frankly, not many programmers are that good, and even fewer have the time to spend hand-rolling low-level code of that quality.

Comment: As always, write the best code you can, that most accurately captures your intent for both human readers and compilers. Then profile and address any specific performance issues as they arise. Scott Meyers' "Effective STL" (either the original thesis and the subsequent book) is an enlightening look at the efficiences that can be gained by using a well-designed and -written code library.

Comment: @Pieter The OP addressed that point and it's part of my assumption. This seems more like a theoretical question than a question concerning actual ability.

Comment: @deceze: Fair enough, my wording was rushed; but is it truly possible to over-emphasize the point?

Comment: zen of assembly language by michael abrash, can get a used copy for next to nothing.  It was outdated when it came out and being 8088/86 based it is even more so now, but the real meat of the book has nothing to do with the particular processor but the thought process behind finding the cycle stealers and what to do with them.  In that respect it is as valid today as it ever was, I still use what I learned there on a daily basis on modern systems, now a couple of decades later.  any of his writings from then to the present are also good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, low-level vs. high-level is not a well-defined language attribute.  It tends to be used to refer to the accessibility of primitive machine capabilites, to the abstraction facilities the language provides, and again to describe the specific abstraction level of available libraries.  And while these aspects are arguably correlated, they are not dependably so -- none of them is required for another.

Lack of access to machine primitives naturally removes flexibility for general-purpose performance programming, but languages without such access can achieve high performance for particular domains by using libraries and/or runtimes that are specialized for that domain (e.g., NumPy and Matlab performance with linear algebra).

Poor abstraction facilities make design, development, use, reuse, and maintenance harder.  This doesn't necessarily impact *potential* performance directly -- but practically speaking, efforts put into mechanics aren't being used to improve performance.  Likewise, lack of high-level libraries doesn't necessarily impact performance directly, but poorly-built re-implementations of essential facilities can have the same effect.

---

So, to answer your question:  in no aspect does language "level" generally determine performance.  But, there is always a "but"...

Additionally, there are costs to "wide-spectrum" languages such as C++, which combine access to primitive capabilities with good abstraction facilities and extensive libraries:  complexity and cognitive load, which (IMHO) are the drivers of the aforementioned correlation between the different aspects of language "level".